# Comparing rows in Data Studio

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, google, google-cloud, google-data-studio

I am using Data Studio for a project and I am connecting to my BigQuery table.

My table contains following columns:

- Date
- Store_name
- Footfall

I'd love to compare the footfall of two stores using Data Studio but apparently I can't do that!

Any hints or should I just switch to another viz tool?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site! I think that you should be asking yourself "why" you can't do this in Data Studio. The likely answer is that Data Studio is a visualization tool while you are looking to do a transform of your existing data.

Most visualization tools are really only good at handling data in it's final form. It sounds like you still need to work on the data a little more to get to that stage. You should consider doing some SQL and/or scripting work (python, R, Julia, whatever) on your data to get it ready in the right format prior to importing it into Data Studio. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I have prepared my data and If I want to do what I asked about I'll have a 80k columns tables !